# Welche Bedeutung hat das Wort "an", wenn es eine Speise beschreibt?

Tags: word-choice, meaning-in-context

Vor allem in der Haute Cuisine werden Speisen derweil mit dem Wort "an" bezeichnet. Wie mir scheint, besonders häufig in Verbindung mit Saucen. Beispielsweise könnte man die klassische Kombination von Spargel und Sauce Hollandaise als *"Spargel an Sauce Hollandaise"* bezeichnen. Hingegen gibt es auch die Verwendung mit "und" oder "mit": Etwa *"Pommes und Ketchup"* oder *"Spaghetti mit Tomatensauce"* sind die ersten Beispiele, die mir spontan einfallen. Hier scheint es einen qualitativen Unterschied zu geben, aber das mag an dem Beispiel liegen.

**Welche Bedeutung hat hier das Wort "an"? Wie setzt es sich von "und" oder "mit" ab?**

---

What is the meaning of "an" when describing a dish? What is its relationship to "und" or "mit"?

Comment: Das heisst, dass man in der Küche die Sachen *nebeneinander* legen musste, damit der Teller einigermaßen voll aussieht ;)

Answer (score 14):

Es gibt traditionelle Essen, bei denen das Essen in Soße "ertränkt" wird.

Die feine Küche versuchte sich davon abzusetzen und serviert das Essen nicht mit Soße über dem Essen, sondern trennt die Bestandteile des Essens auf dem Teller von der Soße.

Optisch sind damit Essen (z. B. ein Stück Fleisch oder die Beilagen) und die Soße getrennt, sie liegen aneinander, aber nicht übereinander. Der Esser kann dann selbst entscheiden, ob er beim Essen mit oder ohne Soße essen will – und wie viel er will.

Es gab viele Witze mit dem *an*, es hat inzwischen auch die Bedeutung "ganz nett zum Essen, aber satt wird man davon nicht".

Ich glaube, das *Essen an X* war eine Modeerscheinung, die nicht mehr so viel verwendet wird.

Comment: Trotzdem bin ich auch der Meinung, es ist bei der (vermeintlich) feineren Küche zu suchen. Das "an" klingt irgendwie etwas edler. Dies wiederum, spekuliere ich einfach mal, könnte aus der französchen Küche stammen: *Asperges aux sauce hollandaise* oder *Filet de boeuf à la moutarde*. Die Wörter *aux* und *à* wurden dann "eingedeutscht".

Answer (score 2):

If you gave a formal definition that covered all examples, you'd get the same definition for all three usages: Something to eat together with something to eat.

In the conotation, you can get some difference:

- und: *Could* mean, that both parts are more or less of equal importance.
- mit: *Could* mean, that the second part is of less importance than the first part.
- an: *Could* mean, that the parts are locally distributed in a special way.

In the level of usage, you indeed have difference:

- an: Is used in/for Haute Cuisine or if Haute Cuisine is pretended.
- mit and und: Are used in all kinds of cuisine.

Answer (score 1):

Doing a rather quick research I found **`an`** only in *Dresden*. Surprisingly together with `Spätzle`. Concerning `Soße`, *München* and *Hamburg* have **`mit`**, whereas *Köln* and *Dresden* have **`in`**.

I assume it is also related to the habits / origin of the executive chef cook.

*Köln*

> Vegan: Tortellini mit Tofufüllung **in Basilikumsauce**, dazu zwei Beilagen
>
> Gemischte Pilze **in Rahm** mit Eieromelette

*München*

> Schweinebraten **mit Biersauce**
>
> Schweinelachssteak **mit Paprikasauce**

*Dresden*

> Rindergeschnetzeltes mit Rote Bete, Gewürzgurke und Rotwein **an Spätzle**, dazu Salat
>
> Kohlroulade **in deftiger Bratensoße**, dazu Schmorkraut und Petersilienkartoffeln

*Hamburg*

> Hähnchenbrust im Knuspermantel **mit Erdnußsoße**, pikantem Möhrengemüse und mit Reis 
>   mit Geflügel
>
> Hausgemachter Gemüsebratling **mit Kerbelsoße** und Gemüse- Zartweizen

Comment: This would only be informative if it was a representative study. Naming some examples from somewhere does not provide any evidence at all.

Answer (score 0):

Ich habe, neben den bereits von knut [bereits erwähnten](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/6541/555) Dingen, immer eine weitere Empfindung was das betrifft: Nämlich dass "an" auch immer einen wahrnembaren Mengenunterschied bedeutet.

Das erwähnte "Essen an X" würde ich immer auch deuten als: "Viel Essen, weniger X". Bei "Steak an Pfeffersauce" ist eigentlich implizit klar dass man mehr Steak als Sauce bekommt, aber bei "Steak an Spargel" wird für mich eine Erwartungshaltung von "Weniger Spargel, mehr Steak" deutlicher als bei "Steak mit Spargel".